# Why doesn't my MVC5 Post Action model get populated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one model in my solution that does not populate in my POST form action.  Why is this model different?

Here is the model that will not bind in my Post action:

```
public class CompanyListingParameters
{
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public String CityState { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the live form (as pulled from chrome debugger):

```
<form class="panel form-horizontal" method="post" action="/company/search" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title">
                    <i class="panel-title-icon fa fa-search fa-3x"></i>
                    Find a Company
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body padding-sm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <label class="control-label sr-only" for="Category">Category</label>
                        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
                        <input type="text" id="Category" name="Category" value="Architecture" class="autocomplete required form-control form-group-margin ui-autocomplete-input" data-autocomplete-url="/api/servicecategory/search/" data-autocomplete-url-method="get" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <label class="control-label sr-only" for="CityState">City, State</label>
                        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
                        <input type="text" id="CityState" name="CityState" value="" class="autocomplete required form-control form-group-margin ui-autocomplete-input ui-autocomplete-loading" data-autocomplete-url="/api/companyservicelisting/area/cities/search" data-autocomplete-url-method="get" data-autocomplete-itemtemplate="CityAutocomplete" data-autocomplete-itemvalue="FormattedAddress" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Search" name="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            </div>
        </form>
```

And the controller code:

```
    [RoutePrefix("company/search")]
    public partial class CompanySearchController : Controller
    {
        [Route("")]
        public virtual ActionResult Search(String category, String cityState)
        {
            var model = ...; //This action works - search results view
            return View(MVC.CompanySearch.Views.Search, model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public virtual ActionResult SearchPost(CompanyListingParameters search)
        {   //parameter 'search' is null here
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.CityState) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.Category)
                ? RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.Index())
                : RedirectToAction(MVC.CompanySearch.Search(search.Category.ToLower(), search.CityState.ToLower()));
        }
}
```

If I change the non-functional action to this, then it works (Category and CityState are bound):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public virtual ActionResult SearchPost(String Category, String CityState)
{   //parameters 'Category' and 'CityState' are populated on Post
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CityState) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Category)
        ? RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.Index())
        : RedirectToAction(MVC.CompanySearch.Search(Category.ToLower(), CityState.ToLower()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, remove `name="Search"` from your submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

The value of submit buttons are posted back, so you are sending `Search:"Search"` in the post, so the `ModelBinder` is trying to bind typeof `CompanyListingParameters` to a string (which of course fails). And unless you have some javascript, the `id` attribute seems unnecessary.

Comment: Wow, this worked!  Thanks.  Although I have to admit this requirement is lame.  Why can't the model binder be smarter and just fill in the properties that do match form fields and ignore the one the model doesn't define?  The model binder works in Web API posts in similar scenarios.

Comment: Why is the ModelBinder trying to bind CompanyListingParameters to a string?  I have three form fields coming back, all of which are strings.  And when only two came back it finds the correct properties.  Is the issue that ModelBinder must find a match for all form fields or the whole deal is off?

Comment: Whats happening is the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of `CompanyListingParameters`, then assigning the values of `Category` and `CityState` from `FormCollection`, then it reads another value named `search` which matches you parameter name so it tried to set `CompanyListingParameters` to the string "Search" (the value of the button) which it cant bind so it becomes `null`. Note you could also solve this by changing the parameter name to anything except the name of one of the values you post back.

Comment: I did try to name the other form fields search.CityState and search.Category and that didn't work.  Or maybe it did and the button 'search' was last and won.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the name of the button matches the name of the parameter. If you kept the button name as "Search" but change the parameter name to "ABC" or "XYZ" it will work fine (but why give a button a name unless you want to post its value back)